# How to keep user information after login in JavaFX Desktop Application

Tags: java, javafx-2, desktop-application, session-storage

I have an application with login screen, after the user is authenticated some "data" is retrieved from a database (username and privileges), until here everything is well.

After the login process I need to access to the privileges to generate some menus across different JavaFX scenes, this all throughout the entire application in any moment, but I don´t know how to do it.

What I am looking for is a behavior such as SESSION variable in PHP (yep, I come from web development), which keeps information alive and accesible during a certain period of time (usually while user is logged in).

The information I have found about this topic is unclear and outdated, I mean, solutions that do not apply for JavaFX 2 or solutions with old design patterns.

I have created an image because in other forums I have found the same question but that is misunderstood, so I hope this could help.

Thanks to everyone.

[image]

Comment: Pass data to new controller will probably do. James D could probably explain how to handle this using MCV pattern.

Comment: The equivalent of "globals" would be a `static` field in some class. However this is bad practice. You should come up with some initialisation process all your scenes go through that involves getting passed the session object (instance of a custom class). Scenes would best be activated by some object dealing with the initialisation of the scenes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **singleton design patter**. For example:

```
    public final class UserSession {

    private static UserSession instance;

    private String userName;
    private Set<String> privileges;

    private UserSession(String userName, Set<String> privileges) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.privileges = privileges;
    }

    public static UserSession getInstace(String userName, Set<String> privileges) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new UserSession(userName, privileges);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public Set<String> getPrivileges() {
        return privileges;
    }

    public void cleanUserSession() {
        userName = "";// or null
        privileges = new HashSet<>();// or null
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserSession{" +
                "userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", privileges=" + privileges +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and use the UserSession whenever you need. When you do login you just call: `UserSession.getInstace(userName, privileges)` and when you do log out: `UserSession.cleanUserSession()`

Comment: Actually, I implemented something similar to this. I didn't want implement singleton pattern, but after developing for Android, I realized this pattern is still being used, with, for example, Firebase. So this is the answer to the question.

Comment: @MAYOBYOHASSAN No, it doesn't... by default singleton design patter is not thread safe, but there is thread safe implementation of the pattern (google it)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Java `Preferences`. At the first successful authentication, you need to write information about user in the `Preferences` like this:

```
Preferences userPreferences = Preferences.userRoot();
userPreferences.put(key,value);
```

And then take the data from the `Preferences`:

```
Preferences userPreferences = Preferences.userRoot();
String info = userPreferences.get(key,value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the user data into a local cache, such as Guava Cache.

for example, we use HashMap to store the user data:

```
class Session{ private HashMap<String,Object> store = new HashMap(); public static final Session INSTANCE = Session(); public void put(String key, Object value){ this.store.put(key,value); } public Object get(String key) { return this.store.get(key); } } in your controller: // call server side API to retrieve user User user = userApi.login(username,password); if(user != null){ Session.INSTANCE.put("USER",user); } // in other class User user = Session.INSTANCE.get("USER");
```

Comment: Please ,can you provide more details ?

Comment: for example, we use HashMap to store the user data:

class Session{
    private HashMap<String,Object> store = new HashMap();
    public static final Session INSTANCE = Session();
    public void put(String key, Object value){
        this.store.put(key,value);
    }
    public Object get(String key) {
        return this.store.get(key);
    }
}

in your controller:
// call server side API to retrieve user
User user = userApi.login(username,password);
if(user != null){
    Session.INSTANCE.put("USER",user);
}

// in other class
User user = Session.INSTANCE.get("USER");